# RxJava, one observable multiple subscribers: publish().autoConnect()

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm playing around with rxJava/rxAndroid and there's something very basic that doesn't behave as I'd expect.
I have this one observable and two subscribers:

```
Observable<Integer> dataStream = Observable.just(1, 2, 3).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

Log.d(TAG, "subscribing sub1...");
dataStream.subscribe(v -> System.out.println("Subscriber #1: "+ integer));

Log.d(TAG, "subscribing sub2...");
dataStream.subscribe(v -> System.out.println("Subscriber #2: "+ integer));
```

And this is the output:

```
D/RxJava: subscribing sub1...
D/RxJava: subscribing sub2...
D/RxJava: Subscriber #1: 1
D/RxJava: Subscriber #1: 2
D/RxJava: Subscriber #1: 3
D/RxJava: Subscriber #2: 1
D/RxJava: Subscriber #2: 2
D/RxJava: Subscriber #2: 3
```

**Now, I know I could avoid repeating the count by using `publish().autoConnect()`** but I'm trying to understand this default behaviour first.
Each time someone subscribe to the observable it starts emitting the number sequence. I get that. So, when when `Subscriber 1` connects it starts emitting items. `Subscriber 2` connects right away, why isn't it getting the values as well?

This is how I understand it, From the perspective of the observable:

1. Someone subscribed to me, I should start emitting items
   **[SUBSCRIBERS: 1][ITEMS TO EMIT: 1,2,3]**
2. Emit item '1' to subscribers
   **[SUBSCRIBERS: 1][ITEMS TO EMIT: 2,3]**
3. Someone else subscribed to me, I'll emit 1,2,3 once again when I'm done
   **[SUBSCRIBERS: 1 & 2][ITEMS TO EMIT: 2,3,1,2,3]**
4. Emit item '2' to subscribers
   **[SUBSCRIBERS: 1 & 2][ITEMS TO EMIT: 3,1,2,3]**
5. Emit item '3' to subscribers
   **[SUBSCRIBERS: 1 & 2][ITEMS TO EMIT: 1,2,3]**
6. Emit item '1' to subscribers
   **[SUBSCRIBERS: 1 & 2][ITEMS TO EMIT: 2,3]**
7. ...

But this is not how it works.
It's like they are two separate observables in one. this confuses me, why don't they give the items to all subscribers?

**Bonus:**

How is that `publish().autoConnect()` fixes the problem?
Let's break it down. `publish()` gives me a connectable observable. a connectable observable is just like a regular observable but you can tell it when to connect. Then I go ahead tell it to connect right away by calling `autoConnect()`

By doing so... don't I get the same thing I started with? A plain regular observable. **The operators appear to cancel each other.**

I could just shut up and use `publish().autoconnect()`. But I'd like to understand more about how observables work.

Thanks!

Comment: I found [this beautiful article](https://medium.com/@maorkorakin/rx-publish-examples-58ae196908f0) super useful. I was looking for `replay()` instead of `publish()`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because in fact those are two separate observables. They are "spawned" when you invoke `subscribe()`. Therefore the steps you have provided are incorrect in sense that step 3 & 4 are just 1 & 2 but on a different observable.

But you see them as 1 1 1 2 2 2 because of thread on which the logging happens. If you were to remove the `observeOn()` part then you would see emissions in a interwoven manner. To see this run code below:

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    final Scheduler single = Schedulers.single();
    final long l = System.nanoTime();
    Observable<Long> dataStream =
            Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
                    .map(i -> System.nanoTime())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
                    //.observeOn(single);

    dataStream.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("1  " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + (i - l)));
    dataStream.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("2  " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + (i - l)));

    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Output, at least in my run was(notice thread names):

```
1  RxComputationThreadPool-1 135376988
2  RxComputationThreadPool-2 135376988
1  RxComputationThreadPool-1 135486815
2  RxComputationThreadPool-2 135537383
1  RxComputationThreadPool-1 135560691
2  RxComputationThreadPool-2 135617580
```

and if you apply the `observeOn()` it becomes:

```
1  RxSingleScheduler-1 186656395
1  RxSingleScheduler-1 187919407
1  RxSingleScheduler-1 187923753
2  RxSingleScheduler-1 186656790
2  RxSingleScheduler-1 187860148
2  RxSingleScheduler-1 187864889
```

As you have correctly pointed out, to get what you want you need the `publish().refcount()` or simply `share()`(it is an alias) operator.

This is because the `publish()` creates a `ConnectableObservable` which does not start emitting items until told to do so via the `connect()` method. in which case if you do this:

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    final Scheduler single = Schedulers.single();
    final long l = System.nanoTime();
    ConnectableObservable<Long> dataStream =
            Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
                    .map(i -> System.nanoTime())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    .observeOn(single)
                    .publish();

    dataStream.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("1  " + (i - l)));
    dataStream.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("2  " + (i - l)));

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    dataStream.connect();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

}
```

You will notice that for the first second(the first `Thread.sleep()` invocation) nothing happens and just after the `dataStream.connect()` is called the emissions happen.

`refCount()` takes in a ConnectableObservable and hides from subscribers the need to call `connect()` by counting how many subscribers are currently subscribed. What it does is upon first subscription it calls `connect()` and after last unsubscription is unsubscribes from the original observable.

As to the mutual cancellation of the `publish().autoConnect()`, afterwards you do get an observable but it has one special property, say that the original observable does an API call over the Internet(lasting 10 second), when you use it without `share()` you will end up with as many parallel queries to the server as there were subscriptions over those 10 seconds. On the other hand with `share()` you will have only one call.

You will not see any upside of it, if an observable that is shared completes its work very fast (like `just(1,2,3)`).

`autoConnect()`/`refCount()` gives you an intermediate observable to which you subscribe to instead of the original observable.

If you are interested dive into this book: [Reactive Programming with RxJava](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/reactive-programming-with/9781491931646/)

Answer (score 13):

### Regular (cold) observable

At the heart of `Observable` is `subscribe` function. Every time new observer subscribes it is passed to this function as a parameter. What this function does, it feeds data into that *single* observer. It does this by calling `observer.onNext` method. It might do this immediately (like `just` does), or via some scheduler (eg. `interval`), or from background thread or callback (eg. by launching some async task).

I highlighted word *single* above because that is the only observer this function knows about when it is invoked. In case you subscribe to such an observable multiple times, its `subscribe` function is called for every subscriber.

Data source like this is called **cold observable**.

### Schedulers

Applying `subscribeOn` operator adds intermediate step between your `subscribe` call and original observable's `subscribe` function. You are no longer calling it directly, but schedule your call via specified scheduler.

`observeOn` adds similar intermediate step to all `onNext` invocations of your observer.

In your example `subscribe` function is called twice, i.e. data series get generated twice. The calls are scheduled via multi-threaded `io` scheduler, so these invocations happen not on main thread but on two other threads, almost simultaneously. Both threads start invoking `onNext` methods of two subscribers. Remember that each thread knows about its own subscriber only. `onNext` calls get scheduled by `mainThread` scheduler, which is single threaded, i.e. they cannot happen simultaneously but need to be queued somehow. **Strictly speaking there can be no guarantee about the ordering of these calls**. It depends on various factors and is implementation specific. Try replacing `just` with `interval` (this will introduce delay between messages) and you'll see that messages will arrive in different order.

### Hot observable

`publish` operator makes your observable *hot*, aka *connectable*. It adds intermediate steps to both `subscribe` function - this is called only once, and to `onNext` methods - these get propagated to all subscribed observables. In other words, *it allows multiple subscribers to share single subscription*.

To be precise, `subscribe` function is called when you invoke `connect` method. There are two operators that invoke `connect` automatically for you:

- `autoConnect` invokes `connect` method when first subscriber comes in. It never disconnects though.
- `refCount` invokes `connect` when first subscriber comes in, and automatically disconnects when last subscriber unsubscribes. It will re-connect (call `subscribe` function again) when new subscribers come in.

`publish().refCount()` is popular combination, so it has got shortcut: `share()`.

For your education try the following code with and without `share`:

```
Observable<Long> dataStream = Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .take(3)
        .share();
System.out.println("subscribing A");
dataStream.subscribe(v -> System.out.println("A got " + v));
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(150);
System.out.println("subscribing B");
dataStream.subscribe(v -> System.out.println("B got " + v));
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
```

### Answers to original questions

1) Cold observable always deals with single subscriber. So your time diagrams shall look like this:

```
subscribed first subscriber
[SUBSCRIBER: 1][ITEMS TO EMIT: 1,2,3]
subscribed second subscriber
[SUBSCRIBER: 1][ITEMS TO EMIT: 1,2,3]
[SUBSCRIBER: 2][ITEMS TO EMIT: 1,2,3]
emit "1" to subscriber 1
[SUBSCRIBER: 1][ITEMS TO EMIT: 2,3]
[SUBSCRIBER: 2][ITEMS TO EMIT: 1,2,3]
emit "1" to subscriber 2
[SUBSCRIBER: 1][ITEMS TO EMIT: 2,3]
[SUBSCRIBER: 2][ITEMS TO EMIT: 2,3]
...
```

Although the order is not guaranteed due to multi-threading races.

2) `publish` and `autoConnect` do not cancel each other. They only add.

```
dataSource = ...;
dataSourceShared = dataSource.publish().autoConnect();
```

Now when you subscribe multiple subscribers to `dataSourceShared` this results in only one subscription to original `dataSource`. I.e. you do not have to emit new series of messages for every new subscriber.

Comment: Beautifully written answer, helped me out a lot!