# RxJava, Can I subscribe and unsubscribe from a observable more than once?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a service running and scanning for BLE devices, over that service I am reading for specific device by knowing the mac address, now the problem comes when I am reading the frames and over those frames that the device is streaming I have to run some process for several minutes, and when the device sends another stream saying that it no longer needs that process running I have to turn it off.

I am using RxJava but I am pretty new to this, so I have an observable that is doing that process so whenever I turn on the process I want to Subscribe to the process and start executing it and when I receive the signal to turn it off, unsubscribe from the Observable.

my question is, I have to run this process many times, can I subscribe and unsubscribe from that observable more than once?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RxJava, one observable multiple subscribers: publish().autoConnect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915738/rxjava-one-observable-multiple-subscribers-publish-autoconnect)

Answer (score 0):

> my question is, I have to run this process many times, can I subscribe and unsubscribe from that observable more than once?

Yes. Simply assign the return value of `Observable.subscribe()` to a `Disposable`, when you want to stop observing/unsubscribe, call `Disposable.dispose()`, then resubscribe to your `Observable` when you want to start observing again.